# Convert MD5 to Long

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, long-integer, xor

I have a 16byte array from MD5 JAVA method.
I want to convert it to a long to use as a hashkey.
Am reading a bitwise XOR the bits to 64 is a good idea... then howto get a long from that?  full code example of XOR and cvt to long please.

Comment: If you were taking the XOR route, you'd just XOR half the bytes with the other half, since long is 64 bits, which is half as many bits as are in a length-16 byte array. More concretely: you could XOR the 8 most significant bytes and the 8 least significant bytes.

Answer (score 5):

The very best solution I found (based on my needs... mix of speed and good hash function) is Google's [CityHash](http://code.google.com/p/cityhash/).  The input can be any byte array including an MD5 result and the output is an unsigned 64-bit long.

CityHash has a very good but not perfect hash distribution, and is very fast.

I ported CityHash from C++ to C# in half an hour.  A Java port should be straightforward too.

Just XORing the bits doesn't give as good a distribution (though admittedly that will be very fast).

I'm not familiar enough with Java to tell you exactly how to populate a long from a byte array (there could be a good helper I'm not familiar with, or I could get some details of arithmetic in Java wrong).  Essentially, though, you'll want to do *something* like this:

```
long a = md5[0] + 
         256 * md5[1] + 
         256 * 256 * md5[2] + 
         256 * 256 * 256 * md5[3] + 
         256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * md5[4] + 
         256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * md5[5] +
         256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * md5[6] +
         256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * md5[7];

long b = md5[8] + 
         256 * md5[9] + 
         256 * 256 * md5[10] + 
         256 * 256 * 256 * md5[11] + 
         256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * md5[12] + 
         256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * md5[13] +
         256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * md5[14] +
         256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 * md5[15];

long result = a ^ b;
```

Note I have made no attempt to deal with [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  If you just care about a consistent hash value on a given platform, though, endianness should not matter.

Comment: CityHash makes extensive use of SSE4 extensions not available in java.

Comment: @Alan: They're not available in C# either afaik, but the C# version was almost exactly as fast as calling the C++ version from C# (so loss of SSE4 is not more expensive than an interop call, give or take).

Comment: You should look at [Guava's Hashing](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.java?name=refs/remotes/gcode-clone/cityhash)

Comment: This is incorrect. A long is 8 bytes, and this solution only sets the 4 least significant bytes of the long. It's a good enough solution if you want to convert an MD5 to an int, but that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 4):

Guava has some very nice [Hashing capabilities](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/HashingExplained):

```
Hashing.md5().hashString(s).asLong();
```

I believe the above is actually CityHash but regardless it will generate hash longs that you can use for whatever your hashing needs. (I tried @Eric J. Java code and it looks like CityHash 32).

Comment: Sorry, but downvote, because It's not CityHash. According to documentation asLong just return first 8 bytes of resulting hash. In your example it will reduce md5's 16 bytes distribution (which is not perfect itself) by half.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, any subsection of a cryptographic digest no longer has many of the cryptographic properties of the digest, specifically these properties no longer hold:

- Inversion resistance (finding an X that satisfies H(X))
- Collision resistance (finding an X, Y such that H(X) = H(Y))
- Random distribution over the range of possible outputs